# Countdown with Views

Tags: views, datetime

i'm trying to format a countdown block in views to look like [image].  This was done with the Countdown Module, however I'd like it to change automatically based on the nearest event date and not have to enter in each event manually.  I can set this up in views, however I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to format it.  Right now it looks like this[image]. So i'd like hence/ago to read since or until after the number of days, followed by the event name.  Thanks for any help!

Sharon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Display Suite, you can create a custom field with the Display Suite Format and use the following (with your own date field name). You could also use a custom PHP field or some kind of hook, but the following logic still applies.

```
<?php
if (!empty($entity->field_event_start)) {

    // Get the starting time value and the timezone.
    $start_value = $entity->field_event_start['und'][0]['value'];
    $timezone = $entity->field_event_start['und'][0]['timezone'];

    // Create the date objects for now and the day of the event.
    $start_date = new DateObject($start_value, $timezone);
    $now = new DateObject(time(), $timezone);

    // Take the difference between now and the beginning date, in days format.
    $duration = $now->difference($start_date, 'days');
    print $duration . ' Days';
}
?>
```

You should end of with something like the following, and then jazz it up with your own styling.

[image: The Days part]

**Edit**

I just realized you wanted "since" as in after, so just switch it up a bit and use the end date instead of the start date, if one exists. I also made a quick video on how to add in the custom code field, so hopefully this helps!

[Custom Date Since field in Display Suite](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5L1Z1pCiK0)

Comment: I haven't used display suite before but will defineitly check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Can this be used in a block? Because this is something I wanted to show in a views block in my sidebar on every page

Comment: Absolutely. Once you set up the view mode (maybe something new like "Sidebar Block") for your content type using DS, in the block display in your view under Format, change Show to **Display Suite** and **Sidebar Block**.

In the DS view mode is where you can put your custom field.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to get this to work.  I've used your code, but changed field_event_start to my field name.  I set up a new view mode called Sidebar block for node entities. I put your code into a new code field for entities node and DS views (wasn't sure here).  Then I selected my view on the views Display tab. Editing my View black I switched the format to display suite using my new Sidebar block view mode, but I not getting anything to show up.

Comment: I went ahead and made a short video tutorial, so that should help you out. Let me know if it works for ya!

Comment: Great - Where can I find it ;) - never mind - found it!

Comment: Works great - thanks so much for your help Kyle. I wasn't setting the fields up in the new view mode for my event :(